# why does it enforce facebook logout if I logout from my website account?

Tags: php, facebook

I have a facebook login button in my website it has two problems :

1. If I logged in to my facebook profile it will log my in automaticlly in my website I can not understand why?. so I want to know how could I log in to my Facebook without enforcing me to log in to my website ?
2. If I logged out from my website-facebook account it will log me out automatically from my facebook page which I do not want it to happened , so I want to know how could I log out from my website without logging out from my facebook account ?

This is my logout page code :

```
<?php  
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) 
{   
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
      'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'cookie' => true,
       ));

     //access token is important for logging out from facebook DO NOT REMOVE IT
         $params = array( 'next' => 'http://www.example.com/','access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken() );
        $logoutlink = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params); // $params is optional.
           //ovewrites the cookie   
        $facebook->destroySession();

        session_destroy();
        header('Location: '.$logoutlink);
}

?>
```

Comment: Both of those things are a perfect example of “works as designed” – they are _supposed_ to work that way.

Comment: ok I know but I mean is there any way to modify this ordinary way to be like I want to be

Answer (score 0):

that is because facebook has a single sign on / single sign off mechanism. 
each time you request login/logout that will affect your facebook session regardless to what application your account has already authorized.

check [oauth2](http://oauth.net/2/) and [saml](http://saml.xml.org/) to understand [SSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) in more details.

Comment: do u mean that I can not control or edit or delete some facebook session variables to make the changes that I want , Because I found some websites that have those features like not login you automatically to your account on your website if you log in to your facebook account until you explicitly log yourself in

Comment: those websites are using facebook account information not facebook sso. they are generating their own session, but in your case you are using facebook session

Comment: is it more secure to use SSO ?

Comment: @Basel more secure than what exactly? if you are asking is it more secure than implementing your own login, I would say that it is, otherwise, you need to be more detailed

Comment: I mean is it more secure to do single sign on / sign off ? or as I asked to do separate sign on for each application and facebook profile?

Comment: @Basel - SSO adds certain layer of security by separating IDP's and SP's in the authorization process. as for other types of security issues, it has nothing to do with it. both approaches might use SSL protocol and data encryption, so in short it is slightly more secure. But, using an IDP such as Facebook is 99% more securely guaranteed than implementing your own authentication.